# Vue.js - Check a checkbox if in arrays

Tags: javascript, checkbox, vue.js

Working on a view that has checkboxes inside a v-for loop:

```
<ul class="object administrator-checkbox-list">
    <li v-for="module in modules">
        <label v-bind:for="module.id">
            <input type="checkbox" v-model="form.modules" v-bind:value="module.id" v-bind:id="module.id" v-if=>
            <span>@{{ module.name }}</span>
        </label>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I also have a data of 'form' (using Laravels Spark Form Object) that has access to a 'currentModules' property that consists of the current resources relationship to a modules table.

I am looking to check the checkboxes that exist in the currentModules property.

Example of the 'modules' data used in the v-for the data:

```
[
    { 
        "id": 1, 
        "name": "Business", 
        "created_at": "2016-11-23 09:57:03", 
        "updated_at": "2016-11-23 09:57:03" 
    },
    { 
        "id": 2, 
        "name": "Houses", 
        "created_at": "2016-11-23 09:57:03", 
        "updated_at": "2016-11-23 09:57:03" 
    }
]
```

And the data from 'form.currentModules' is the exact same format. How can I check the checkboxs if the module id is in the currentModules using Vue?

Comment: Do you also want to add/remove modules from `form.currentModules` when the checkbox is clicked?

Comment: Nope, thats handled elsewhere just need to set them as checked on initial page load. Currently looking to see if a filter will allow me to do this easiest. @asemahle

Answer (score 1):

To select the boxes, you `form.modules` to contain the ids of the selected items, i.e.:

```
data: function () {
  return {
    form: {
      modules: [1, 2]
    },
    // ...
  }
}
```

Check out [this bin](https://jsbin.com/sebokux/10/edit?html,js,output) to see an example :-)